# Path From A->B in Dual Browser in Pathfinder?

Tags: macos, pathfinder

This is something that every dual-browser file manager does with no problem: I would like to change directories in one half of the dual browser to the directory in the other half. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh here it is: [no, you cannot do it at this time](http://forum.cocoatech.com/showthread.php?t=4791&highlight=dual).